# Process std::map<K,V> and std::map<K,V*> in similar way

Tags: c++

I have two types: `std::map<K,V>` and `std::map<K,V*>`, and lot of functions, which operates with `std::map<K,V>` .
Now, I need also to process `std::map<K,V*>` objects by these functions . What is the best way to to implement processing the both types by the same code?

I have function

```
    std::map<K,V>& Process( std::map<K,V>& gData)
{
      for(auto && it: gData )
        //some code
}
```

and a would like to be able use as well:

```
std::map<K,V*>& Process( std::map<K,V*>& gData)
```

I suspect, that I have to write two wrappers, that will call the 'realProcessing' code

```
 std::map<K,V>& Process( std::map<K,V>& gData)
{
//...some here...
  realProcessing(...some arguments...)
}
    std::map<K,V*>& Process( std::map<K,V*>& gData)
{
//...another wrapper here...
  realProcessing(...some arguments...)
}
```

the question is how to implemet this

Comment: Why do you need both values and pointers?

Comment: if your code that works on `std::map<K,V>` is fine with any `V` then it should also be fine with a `std::map<K,W*>`

Comment: Maybe XY problem.

Comment: is it possible that you are not talking about some generic `K` and `V` but that your code works with some specific `K` and `V`? In that case you should tell what the types actually are

Comment: [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) might help.

Comment: As is, this is too broad. `std::map<K, V>` and `std::map<K, V*>` are too unrelated types, as `int` and `char*` are. Without a specific example, we can only provide a generic solution working in every situation. This does not exist in C++.

Comment: Show a sample code, without this it is not clear what exactly you want to solve

Comment: Rather depends on what "operates with" means. If you are only reading values out of these maps, just sprinkling with a template that dereferences `V *` and does nothing to `V &` should be fine

Comment: It hardly depends on how those a lot of functions implemented.

Comment: You can use two functions of the same name overloaded by their parameter, like `void print(std::map<K, V> const& data)` and `void print(std::map<K, V*> const& data)`.  Inside those routines, you can call another routine that is passed the extricated parameters `void print(K const& k, V const& v)` in a loop, one-by-one.  Depends on your particular use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a layer of abstraction.  Lets say you have:

```
std::map<int, int> value_map{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}};
std::map<int, int*> pointer_map{{1,new int(1)},{2,new int(2)},{3,new int(3)}};
```

And you want to iterate them in the same function like:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
void process(std::map<K, V>& data)
{
    for (auto& e : data)
    {
        // use e.second as an int if passed both maps
    }
}
```

What you can do is add a couple functions that will return a reference to the element or what it points to like:

```
template<typename T>
T& get_value(T& element)
{
    return element;
}

template<typename T>
T& get_value(T* element)
{
    return *element;
}
```

Then you could implement `process` like:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
void process(std::map<K, V>& data)
{
    for (auto& e : data)
    {
        auto& element = get_value(e.second);
        // use element here
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfb7701450fa5a50)

Comment: In order to expand 'process' to deal with std::map<K, V*>& data I must copy it's body, which, now will call another ' get_value' overloading. I think it is bad practice

Comment: @Vasliy I don't get the comment.  `process` is is a template so you can pass and `std::map` to it.  If you look at the live example you can see I pass a `std::map<int, int>` and `std::map<int, int*>` to it and it gives the same results.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you, now i understood your solution

Answer (score 0):

Since **`C++17`** you can also use [if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) for these kind of situations, for example:

```
template <typename T>
auto get_value(T t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
        return *t; // deduces return type to int for T = int*
    else
        return t;  // deduces return type to int for T = int
}
```